# Gas stove radiates heat even when off

Tags: stove

My relative rents an apartment with an old gas stove.  Even when off, it radiates heat and is being told that the heat is caused by the pilot light.  This is making it difficult to cool the apartment during the summer.  Could this be true, and if not the cause, what do you think the issue is?  Could the pilot light need to be adjusted?

Answer (score 2):

As Ed Beal mentioned in a comment, something doesn't sound right here. I have a gas range as well, and it's getting over 90* F here lately. I don't have a steamy kitchen. I'd have an appliance tech look at the pilot to see whether it's far too large.

Answer (score 0):

It can be true, the pilot light is there to assure that there is no un-combusted gas leaking out of the system, and to start the system when necessary. It's as much safety as utility. There are probably no adjustments required, it's meant to always be on. You should feel warmth, but it shouldn't be 'hot' in the stove.

-edited- as I was thinking it was [this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=gas+stove&biw=1502&bih=866&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg482o5cbNAhWh5IMKHdp4BQMQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=gas+heating+stove&imgrc=xJTwkZfJqncIuM%3A) kind of stove.

Comment: I would not think a properly adjusted pilot would add more than a few BTU's of heat more than that there is a huge safety problem or someone that is full of ???

Comment: Definitely a potentially huge safety problem. Which is why I can't generally say it's a problem, if they're renting, it would be in the buildings best interest to do spot checks on all appliances they supply for utility and safety.

Comment: I have a gas fireplace with a pilot. I can definitely feel some slight warmth radiating when I place my hand next to the fireplace glass, and I don't consider this abnormal. It also doesn't make the house hard to cool, although I sometimes wonder why I'm paying twice: once for the gas that creates the heat and once for the AC to remove the heat again. I'm sceptical that there's a huge safety problem here or a far too large pilot. More likely a poorly insulated apartment or an undersized AC unit.

Comment: @AndyW in a gas fireplace you can *often* turn the pilot off over summer.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My point was that the pilot wasn't so large a heat load as to hugely motivate me to do that.